# How do you register a custom management command in a Django unittest

Tags: python, django, django-unittest

How do you register a custom Django management command that only exists within a unittest?

In Django 1.5, you could do this like:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.core.management import _commands

from myapp.testse.commands import MyTestCommand

class JobTestCase(TestCase):

    fixtures = ['test_jobs.json']

    def setUp(self):
        # Install the test command; this little trick installs the command
        # so that we can refer to it by name
        _commands['test_command'] = MyTestCommand()
```

However, in Django 1.8, `_commands` no longer exists. Looking in the code, it seems these are now dynamically retrieved via django.core.management.get_commands, but I don't see a method to add or register an arbitrary command class. Is this possible?